# Standard error for a scale parameter estimate?

Tags: statistics

I was just wondering how to find the standard error of a estimate for the scale parameter for a gamma distribution. I know the standard error's of the common point estimators but I'm not sure on how find the standard error for the scale. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For estimating the mean $\mu$ of a normal distribution ($\sigma$ unknown), the 95% CI is of the form $\bar X \pm t^*S/\sqrt{n},$ where $t^*$ cuts probability 0.025 from the upper tail of Student's t distribution with df $n-1$ and $S/\sqrt{n}$ is the (estimated) standard error of the estimate $\bar X$ of $\mu$. 
In this context, the 'standard error' of $\hat \mu = \bar X$ is simply another
terminology for $SD(\hat \mu).$

However, normal $\mu$ is a *location* parameter.
CIs for *scale* parameters are not generally of the form point "estimate $\pm$ (prob factor)(std error)." For data from $\mathsf{Gamma}(shape=\alpha,\,scale=\theta)$ the MLE $\hat \theta = (1/\alpha)\bar X,$ where
$\bar X$ has another gamma distribution. (For details, see the Wikipedia
article on 'gamma distribution' under 'estimation'.)

If $\alpha$ is known, you can get a
CI for $\theta,$ but it will not explicitly use a 'standard error', and the CI
will not be symmetrical about $\hat \theta.$ If $\alpha$ must be estimated,
finding a CI for $\theta$ is messier, and there are various 'simplified'
approximations, but none that I know about use standard errors.

Finally then, if your purpose is to find a CI for $\theta,$ then the 'standard error'
approach does not seem appropriate. If you just want the standard deviation of
$\hat \theta$, that will depend on whether the shape parameter is known or
estimated. If you can be more clear about your purpose and give some context,
maybe one of us can be of more help.